# How to get data based in comparing value in pivote table with value in required table in laravel 5.6?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I am learning larvel 5.6 so I am trying to retrieve number of messages that have id larger than last_seen_id in pivot table

I have user table which have the default columns generated by:

```
php artisan make:auth
```

and messages tables which have the following columns:

id, from, message_content, group_id

and the group table have the columns:

id,type

now there is many to many relation between the users and groups table through the custom pivot table which have the columns:

group_id,user_id,last_id_seen

now if I want to retrieve the messages which belong to same group and have larger id than last_id_seen in the pivot table how to do it?

Comment: you specify 5.6 in your question but have the 5.2 tag? Which one do you have?

Comment: is that wrong? I suppose there will be something in common between all versions of Laravel that is why I added this tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
$groupId = 1; // set to whatever you want    

$lastSeenId = \Auth::user()->groups()
    ->where('group_id', $groupId)
    ->first()->pivot->last_id_seen;
$messages = Message::where('id', '>', $lastSeenId)->get();
```

A more robust version, which does not fail when your user does not have an entry for the group yet, would be:

```
$groupId = 1; // set to whatever you want 

$group = \Auth::user()->groups()->where('group_id', $groupId)->first();
$lastSeenId = $group ? $group->pivot->last_id_seen : null;
$messages = Message::when($lastSeenId, function($query, $id) {
        $query->where('id', '>', $id);
    })->get();
```

*Note: normally you'd use `optional()` in the second snippet, but Laravel 5.2 does not come with this helper...*

---

If you want both the `count()` of the results and the results themselves, you can store the query in a variable and perform two queries with it. You then don't have to rewrite the same query twice:

```
$groupId = 1; // set to whatever you want 

$group = \Auth::user()->groups()->where('group_id', $groupId)->first();
$lastSeenId = $group ? $group->pivot->last_id_seen : null;
$query = Message::when($lastSeenId, function($query, $id) {
        $query->where('id', '>', $id);
    });

$count = $query->count();
$messages = $query->get();
```

Comment: in the robust version I notice you pass two parameters to callback function which are the $query and $id ... what does id refer to? does it refer to $lastSeenId?

Comment: in the robust version I notice you pass two parameters to callback function which are the $query and $id ... what does id refer to? does it refer to $lastSeenId?

Comment: Yes, the second parameter of `$callback` is the first parameter that you give to `when($value, $callback)`. `$callback` will only be called when `$value` evaluates to `true`. The `when()` function simply calls `if($value) { $callback($query, $value); }`.

Comment: do you mind to tell me how to get only the count of the messages that belong to the same group and have id larger than last_id_seen?

Comment: Replace `->get()` with `->count()` and you are already there. I'll make a short addition to my answer which explains it.